# Calling function or value from server side to html aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On my aspx, I have a client control which needs to receive a value from server side.

```
<tr>
    <td >
        <a class="lnk_abrepopup"
           title="MyPage.aspx?Cod_OP=<%# Return_CodOP() %>">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Property **title** should receive a value. I call function Return_CodOP() which is declared in server side code behind like this:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
Protected Function Return_CodOP() As String
        Return _Cod_OP
        '' Even if I put like Return "4", it gives nothing when it's called from html aspx
End Function
```

The thing is that in html aspx, function Return_OP() returns nothing. Maybe because there is no postback.

Is there any way to resolve this thing or some work around?

Comment: The regular way to do this is to use a property instead of calling your function in the aspx.  Perhaps populate your property on page load.

Comment: use jquery ajax postback

Answer (score 0):

When I use this type of coding I usually type it out as ....

```
<tr>
  <td >
    <a class="lnk_abrepopup" title="MyPage.aspx?Cod_OP=<%=Return_CodOP()%>">
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```